# free and paid registration guest user in my website using paypal using php please help me

Tags: php, html, css, paypal

In my site i want to free and paid membership.

I am new in paypal integration. How to use paypal payment system please help me.

After insert this detail in database and how to redirect on paypal.

Duration : 1year, 2year and lifetime membership
Prize :$10 ,$20, $100

Here is my PHP code

```
function payment_info()
{
global $obj;
    $jobseeker_id = $_SESSION['jobseeker_logged_in_id'];

        $s=$obj->FetchObject("SELECT * FROM candidate_registration WHERE jobseeker_id='".$jobseeker_id."'");
        $fname =$s->candidate_fname;
        $candidate_lname =$s->candidate_lname;
        $candidate_name =$fname.' '.$candidate_lname; 
        $candidate_current_location =$s->candidate_current_location;
        $candidate_mob =$s->candidate_mob;
        $candidate_dob =$s->candidate_dob;
        $candidate_gender =$s->candidate_gender;
        $email_id =$s->email_id;

        $duration = $_REQUEST['item_name'];
        $pid = $_REQUEST['item_number'];
        $prize = $_REQUEST['amount'];
        $sql_data_array=array('pid'=>$pid,
                              'jobseeker_id'=>$jobseeker_id,
                              'duration'=>$duration,
                              'prize'=>$prize,
                              'email_id'=>$email_id,
                              'jobseeker_name'=>$candidate_name,
                              'candidate_current_location'=>$candidate_current_location,
                              'candidate_mob'=>$candidate_mob,
                              'candidate_gender'=>$candidate_gender,
                              'candidate_dob'=>$candidate_dob,
                              'membership_status'=>'1',
                              'membership_date'=>'now()');
    $obj->Insert('jobseeker_member',$sql_data_array);
    $_SESSION['success']="user detail added successfully";  
    header("location:");
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on the above code after this line `$obj->Insert('jobseeker_member',$sql_data_array);` you want to set your paypal integration which are redirect to paypal with all the elements in paypal.

Comment: Integrated with paypal see google paypal manual